# Moving every child

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a game object that has a lot of children (spheres)

[image]

At some stage of the game I'd like to move every child down smoothly so it would look like it's falling apart. What I've tried is using `foreach` loop to move every element with `Vector3.Lerp`. Sadly everything starts lagging very badly.

Would be great to have them fall down smoothly like this

[image]

```
foreach (Transform child in GameObject.Find("Carbon").transform)
{
        child.transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(child.transform.position, 
                                    new Vector3(child.transform.position.x,
                                                child.transform.position.y - 200,
                                                child.transform.position.z), 0.2f);
}
```

Comment: If you want to get the effect of the structure "falling apart", you could assign each child a disabled rigid body (and optionally a sphere collider) in the editor, then enable them all (using a foreach loop) when it's time for them to fall away. This _might_ yield better performance than so many separate interpolations on the main thread.

Comment: If you are not using physics to move the objects then remove the rigidbody and collider components if there are any. You should also use [`Time.DeltaTime`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-deltaTime.html) for smooth movement if you're moving the objects in the update function.

Answer (score 3):

I think the main problem comes from `GameObject.Find()`. From the look of your code, it finds carbon transform in every `foreach`. If you have 100 objects it will use "GameObject.Find" 100 times in one frame.
This can be fixed by caching transform:

```
List<Transform> carbonList = new List<Transform>();

void Start () {
    //cache carbon tranform in Start() or OnEnable()
    carbonList.AddRange( transform.GetComponentsInChildren<Transform>());//use this if you attach your code in object parent

    //loop transform form caching list so it will not keep finding transform and cause lagging
    foreach (Transform child in carbonList)
    {
        var childPos = child.position;
        child.position = Vector3.Lerp(childPos, new Vector3(childPos.x, childPos.y - 200, childPos.z), 0.2f);
    }
}
```

if your script is not in parent object you can use find tag instead.
http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/24257/how-do-i-find-all-game-objects-with-the-same-name.html

Answer (score 0):

Your animation graphic seems to show that all of your spheres maintain the same relative position to each other.  Rather than "falling apart", they seem to be falling together as a body.  If that's want you want, rather than animate each individual sphere, put them all under a single parent object and animate that parent.